# WD20EARS 2TB Compatibility Issues

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, sata

I have a system that runs the Asus P5Q Pro mother board and I recently added the 2TB WD Green HDD (WD20EARS).  I formatted it NTFS with MBR.  The system has been running for a week now without any problems and then tonight the system locked up on me as I was copying some files around.  When I went to reboot, Windows 7 locks up at the windows logo and doesn't go any further.  When I reboot again, I then get asked to perform a startup repair.  When I run that, nothing is found and the problem is not resolved.  When I unplug my new HDD, I am able to get back into Windows with no problems.

So there is obviously a compatibility issue between my MB and my HDD but don't have a clue where to start so that I can resolve this issue.

Comment: Ears are a special kind of drive, only weird people can get them to work :-)  I have to use mine with the sector shift in permanent or some disk things go bonkers.  http://www.wdc.com/global/products/features/?id=7 I do not know if ANY of that or this will help.  I get them cheap because nobody wants em :-)  they also like to go to sleep quick, some utility that is not supposed to work changed that.  I cant get good info because people did the right things, and I instead did the wrong things, and they work great.

Comment: http://wdc.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/5655/p/227%2C294/c/123/session/L2F2LzEvc25vLzEvdGltZS8xMzE3ODg1MDE3L3NpZC81R1JlbFNGaw%3D%3D
switching that pin , all data will turn to mud , and will prementally  Destroy all data if it gets checkdisked with it shifted.  so DONT change it! just understand it.

win7 does not need the sector shift and understands 4096K sector drives, but other stuff i used did not.

Answer (score 0):

Download and run the [Western Digital Data Lifeguard diagnostic tools](http://support.wdc.com/product/download.asp?groupid=612&sid=30&lang=en), burn the ISO to CD as an Image, then boot from it and test the EARS drive, run the extended tests.

Answer (score 0):

I would check on that mother board see if there's any new bios update. It's quite possible there's a problem with the board not liking that drive maybe there's some sort of update?